# Concatenate logs by ID and time using Kafka Streams - Failed to flush state store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to concatenate logs by ID within a window of time using Kafka Streams.

For now, I can successfully count the number of logs having a same ID (the commented code).

However, when I replace the `.count` method with `.aggregate` I face following error:

```
"Failed to flush state store time-windowed-aggregation-stream-store"
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I'm new to this and can't figure out the cause of this error, I think that having `.withValueSerde(Serdes.String())` is supposed to prevent this.

Below my code:

```
package myapps;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.WindowStore;

public class MyCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-mycode");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");
        KStream<String, String> changedKeyStream = source.selectKey((k, v)
         -> v.substring(v.indexOf("mid="),v.indexOf("mid=")+8));

        /* // Working code for count
        changedKeyStream
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
        .grace(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
        .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long())) // could be replaced with an aggregator (reducer?) ? 
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
        .toStream()
        .print(Printed.toSysOut());
        */

        changedKeyStream
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))

        .aggregate(
        String::new, (String k, String v, String Result) -> { return Result+"\n"+v; },
        Materialized.<String, String, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("time-windowed-aggregated-stream-store") /* state store name */
        .withValueSerde(Serdes.String())) /* serde for aggregate value */
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
        .toStream()
        .print(Printed.toSysOut());

        changedKeyStream.to("streams-mycode-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        // launch until control+c
        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.print("Something went wrong!"); 
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

There are two option to fix it:

1. Pass `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped` to `KStream::groupByKey`.
2. Set `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde` to Materialized - `Materialized::withKeySerde(...)`

Sample code bellow:

Ad 1.

```
changedKeyStream
  .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))
```

Ad 2.

```
changedKeyStream
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))
  .aggregate(
    String::new, (String k, String v, String Result) -> { return Result+"_"+v; },
    Materialized.<String, String, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("time-windowed-aggregated-stream-store") /* state store name */
      .withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
      .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
   )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'm not facing the errors mentioned anymore, however, I'm not seeing the concatenated messages (I was able to see an output when using .count method commented in my code).
Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: @ZineddineB., remove /tmp/kafka-streams directory and restart your broker and application

Comment: I removed the directory, restarted the machine, the application and recreated the topics but I'm still facing the same issue, any ideas please?

Comment: @ZineddineB., try to change value for `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG`